# Main-nav li a:hover not working when I change the zoom size

Tags: html, css

My hover code is only working on a specific zoom size, which is 67% for all of the the boxes. However, when I zoom to 80% only two work. When I zoom in to 100% only one works. I will provide the parts that are used. I need my code to show where the boxes are for main-nav in different zoom-ins please help. Here is the HTML & CSS code thank you:

**HTML**
...

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="LogoSmall.jpg">
    </div>

  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li class="active"><a>Sell Your House</a></li>
    <li><a href="">How It Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Compare</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="title">
    <h1>Sell Your House Today<br>
    Get Started Now...</h1>

      <div class="button">

        <a href="" class="btn btn-one">Get Started</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-two">Learn More</a>

      </div>

  </div>

</header>
```

**CSS**
...

```
.main-nav
{
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

header
{
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(HouseJPEG.jpeg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.main-nav li
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a
{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.main-nav li.active a
{
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a:hover
{
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.logo img
{
  width: 140px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

body
{
  font-family: monospace;
}

.row
{
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im kind of new to programming and to this website. I copied your code and it worked fine for me. Im using Google Chrome right now and no matter how much I zoom in, the hover effect always does its job. You could try specifying the viewport in the  area by:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
```

!DOCTYPE html is to tell the browser to use HTML5 but what you should really be looking at is the meta viewport. I hope this helps